# google gmap update on selected option id

Tags: jquery, google-maps, attributes

I'd like to display update a map google position depending on a select list uploaded from a database by using the option "id"'s. I think I'm close to the result expected but still can't figure out where the problem come from. The current result is that gmap_city remain empty.

```
<select id="city_list">
<option selected="selected" id="40.7305991000,-73.9865812000" value="2">New York, United States</option>
// here is a query that display the following options
<option id="<?php echo $latlng;?>" value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $name;?</option>    
</select>


<script>
$('#city_list').change(function(){
    var coordinate = $(this).attr('id');
    google_map(coordinate);
});

function google_map(coordinate){
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_city'),
    mapOptions);
} 
</script>

<div id="gmap_city" style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:3px; width:540px; height:220px; border:5px solid white;"></div>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues related to the question:

1. `$(this).attr('id')` refers to the id of the select, not to the id of the selected option
2. `google.maps.LatLng` expects 2 arguments, you must split the string and pass lat and lng separate

Other issues:

1. You create a new Map-instance on each change, you better use a single Map-instance and set the center `onchange`
2. Although your ID's would be valid in HTML5, you better us another attribute to store the latlng(value would be proper and easier to access)

---

```
<select id="city_list">
<option selected="selected" data-latlng="[43.7305991000,-73.9865812000]" >1</option>
<!--more options-->
</select>
<script>
function google_map(){
  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_city'),
            mapOptions);

  $('#city_list').change(function(){
        var coordinate = $('option:selected',this).data('latlng')
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate[0],coordinate[1]));
    }).trigger('change');
}  
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', google_map);
</script>
```

Comment: The fact is I'm using 'id' instead of 'value' because the select list is included in a form and I do "POST" the value to use it later therefore it is not available for the latlng.. That is why I've tried with 'id'. Maybe there is another solution? Btw thanks for the answer!

Comment: It may be any attribute, e.g. a data-attribute(I've updated the code)